# Python: pattern for functions that handles and return multiple types

Tags: python, overloading

I am working on a python project with users using lists, numpy arrays, pandas series, dataframes and indices. Many functions do operations that apply to all these types and I wonder what the best pattern would be to define many such functions.

**Example**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def func1a(data):
    '''Branching example function that does (more or less) the same thing for many types.'''
    
    if isinstance(data, list):
        return list(x for x in data if x > 0)
    
    if isinstance(data, (np.ndarray, pd.Series)):
        return data[data > 0]
    
    if isinstance(data, pd.DataFrame):
        return data.loc[data.index > 0]


def func1b(data):
     '''Branching example function that transforms the data for many types.'''
    
    if isinstance(data, list):
        return list(x**2 for x in data)
    
    if isinstance(data, (np.ndarray, pd.Series, pd.DataFrame)):
        return data**2
```

My wished requirements is that the user should be able to pass any of the types listed above to the function and get the same type back, with the processing specified by the type.

There are many functions to implement this for and I am looking for a pythonic way of doing it, and a good way of writing tests for them (I'm using pytest).

I have tried just simple branching as in `func1a` but it is hard to reuse code for the processing in that case. I've also tried recursive calls like `func2a` to keep most of the processing for one data type, convert input to that type and convert back when returning:

```
def func2a(data):
    '''Recursive example. This particular sloppy return messes up index/column
    structures etc. Can combine with branching with type specific conversions back    
    and forth to retain specific type consideration but keep most of the 
    processing for one data type.'''
    
    if isinstance(data, np.ndarray):
        return data[data > 0]
    
    return type(data)(func2(np.array(data)))


def func2b(data):
    '''Recursive example for transformations.'''

    if isinstance(data, np.ndarray):
        return data**2
    
    if isinstance(data, pd.Series):
        return pd.Series(func2b(data.to_numpy()), index=data.index)
    
    if isinstance(data, pd.DataFrame):
        return pd.DataFrame(func2b(data.to_numpy()),
                           index=data.index,
                           columns=data.columns)
    
    return type(data)(func2(np.array(data)))
```

After reading a bit more about it, I have come across `functools.singledispatch` and `typing.overload` but these are new concepts to me and I don't know which is best nor how to do it in the best way, or if there are better ways.

Ideally, I would like to write one function with core processing and then just specify which types it would apply for. For transforming functions (like `func2b`), which pretty much always does the same thing with indices/columns etc., it would be cool with automatic type handling (perhaps a decorator like `@accepts_my_standard_types` if possible or something similar).

Comment: If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Comment: I don't really see anything wrong with `func1a`.  If you wanted, I suppose you could write `func1a_list`, `func1a_array`, `func1a_df` and have `func1a` be a simple dispatcher.  That would allow you to cut-and-paste the base `func1a` pretty easily.

Comment: @TimRoberts The real functions may have many lines of complex processing and my intention was to only have one code to deal with that.